# foreign key in my database migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am developing a program in laravel, I am always creating database while I'm writing my code. And now, I want to test my program, so I reset all my database, and try to migrate, suddenly this error appear, anyone know why ?

`` SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'paket' already exists (SQL: create table `paket` (`id` int unsigned not null aut o_increment primary key, `produk_id` int unsigned not null, `nama` varchar(191) not null, `jumlah_user` int not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci) ``

And this is my database migration :

1. User :

   `public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('username')->unique();
           $table->string('email')->unique();
           $table->string('level');
           $table->string('password');
           $table->rememberToken();
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }`
2. a table named paket:

   ````
   ```public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('paket',function(Blueprint $table){
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->integer('produk_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('produk_id')->references('id')->on('produk');
         $table->string('nama');
         $table->integer('jumlah_user');
         // $table->date('tanggal_mulai');
         // $table->date('tanggal_terakhir');
         $table->timestamps();
       });
   }```
   ````
3. a table named harga :

   `public function up()
   {
     Schema::create('harga',function(Blueprint $table){
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->integer('paket_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('paket_id')->references('id')->on('paket');
       $table->decimal('harga',13,2);
       $table->string('masa_training');
       $table->string('masa_maintenance');
       $table->date('tanggal_efektif');
       $table->timestamps();
     });
   }`
4. A table named produk

   `public function up()
   {
     Schema::create('produk',function(Blueprint $table){
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('nama');
       $table->timestamps();
     });
   }`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved.
Thanks.

======
What i do is : migrate the table from master, and ordered it so i migrate all table that have ID (that is a foreign ID in other table) first.
What i do to make that happend is just rename the timestamp in my file name.

Comment: although it solves your problem but this approach is not recommended. We must not change timestamps to correct the order. Rather you should add another migration which changes your existing tables to match the correct/new schema.

Comment: @NaumanZafar but isnt it fine since im still in developing the program?

Comment: this is a matter of best practice. I also once had urge to do the same for similar situations. Your project is in development phase, And might not have large no. of tables yet. Just imagine, If the migration you changed timestamps for have dependency on multiple migrations. You will end up fixing the mess. 

If we follow the conventions for migrations. we will save a alot of time & effort.